# How to mark as READ all the e-mails received in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, messages, mobile-mail

It's fine when you are clearing all your unread messages in a laptop or a desktop PC; but in iPhone? No good.

You see, at present, I mark my messages as read by individually tapping their checkboxes.

I'm not sure if the developers of iPhone thought about including this feature. But I'd like to find out is if there's a trick or I don't know, maybe there's something that would allow me to mark multiple messages to be already read not by checking them one-by-one?

I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://lifehacker.com/5916375/how-to-mark-all-emails-as-read-on-your-iphone-with-one-simple-trick) on Lifehacker a few days ago shows a trick to mark all emails as read.

Quoting the article:

> Open up the Mail app and tap the Edit button.
>   Select one message.
>   Press and hold the Mark button at the bottom of the screen.
>   While still pressing and holding the Mark button, tap the email you previously selected to unmark it.
>   Release the Mark button.
>   Tap the Mark as Read button.

Comment: That doesn't work for me anymore ( iPhone 4 with iOS 6.0) the mail app just freezes up.